# Handling variables in composition relationships

Tags: c++, oop, composition

I am currently redesigning a C++ project, and wanted some opinions on how variables should be handled when classes with a "has a" (composition) relationship need to access variables that arguably belong to the parent, for example:

A computer object has a network card object. The computer object has an owner variable. For example

```
class Computer {
        string get_owner(); // getter as an option?
    private:
        std::string owner = "baylesj";
        NetworkCard nic;
}

class NetworkCard {
    public:
       NetworkCard(Computer *parent);
       send_packet();
       broadcast_owner(send_packet(m_parent->owner)); // this is kind of ugly
    private:
        Computer *m_parent;
}
```

Let's say I have a function in network card that needs the owner. Is it better to pass the owner in as a member variable of network card when I initialize in in Computer, or should I have a parent pointer in NetworkCard that can access the member variable of Computer, a Getter/Setter, or some other relationship? I know it's fairly common practice to have a pointer to parent in the child, but is it a good idea / proper OOP?

**The computer thing is just for example, IRL it's something else so don't get too hung up over it :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you recognize that it is desirable to minimize unnecessary coupling. To do so you can design the NetworkCard class to be unaware of the implementation details of the parent.  Here is one approach that passes the name to broadcast at network construction:

```
class Computer {
    public:
        Computer(std::string const &owner) : m_Owner(owner), nic(owner)
        {
        }

    private:
        std::string m_Owner;
        NetworkCard nic;
};

class NetworkCard {
    public:
       NetworkCard(std::string const &owner)
       {
           broadcast_owner(owner);
       }

       send_packet();
       broadcast_owner(std::string const &owner);

    private:
};
```

If you find there are too many such variables to pass as constructor parameters (I like no more than two or three), then you might discover that composition is the wrong tool for the problem.  Often the number of parameters is small unless it is actually an "is-a" relationship, in which case inheritance might be a better tool.

Comment: Thanks, that helps me get pointed in the right direction. I especially appreciate the tip on checking the number of constructor params to tell if it should be an "is-a".

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful.  You'll get a good feel for it after you do a few of them.